# Azure VM Outbound Connection SFTP Timeout

Tags: azure, networking, traceroute

By default i know you cannot ping or traceroute from azure, however i need to try and troubleshoot an outbound connection to an SFTP server that we are currently seeing timeouts.

Is there any way at all, we can get information relating to which stage the connection is failing?

I am thinking this might have something to do with NAT translation, but i have no idea how to prove it?

Ty,

Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, we do not support ping from Azure and there is no work around for this.